# Getting the error like Cannot find module at Function.Module._resolveFilename while run LoopBack framework(Node.js) based example

Tags: node.js, microservices, strongloop, loopback

I am getting the follow error while run the application. This application based on LoopBack framework(Node.js).

**Cannot find module at Function.Module._resolveFilename(module.js:547.15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js : 474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain(module.js : 191:16)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js : 191.16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3**

Please see : https://www.screencast.com/t/9WK72r9jAk0l

I have removed the 'npm' & 'npm-cache' as well from '\AppData\Roaming' folder.

I don't know how to resolve this error. 
Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried removing `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the dependencies with `npm i`?

Comment: Yes, I did the same but still errors are persist.

Comment: Please see error log : https://www.screencast.com/t/uaOxipWarBl

Comment: That looks like a Windows error, related to your path. Please try to follow [these troubleshooting steps](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Installation-troubleshooting.html#windows-issues) to see if it's repaired. And try to install dependencies again with `npm i`